# How to add objects to draw in runtime using GLES20?

Tags: android, opengl-es, gles20

In my simple GLES20 app I'm trying to add some objects in runtime to draw. 
In my Renderer class I have ArrayList of Squares:

```
private ArrayList<Square> mSquares = new ArrayList<Square>();
```

Here is my [Square](https://gist.github.com/ashchuk/9a90f3120aabf9bb3402103f78eca817) class.

`Square` is drawing well if create it in `onSurfaceCreated`.

But what I'm actually want to do. I need to add new `Square` into `mSquares` in runtime by button clicking and draw squares in `onDrawFrame`.

In my Renderer class I created `AddFigure()` method:

```
public void AddFigure(float x, float y, float z)
{                                                     // color                   coords    angle
    mSquares.add(new Square("Red square", new float[] {1, 0, 0, 1}, new float[] {x, y, z}, 100f));
}
```

I'm invoking this method by clicking on the button in my Activity:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                mGLRenderer.AddFigure(1f, 1f, 1f);
        }
    });
```

But it always throwing this exceptions:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 220
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

and

```
E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
E/emuglGLESv2_enc: device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glEnableVertexAttribArray:741 GL error 0x501
Info: Invalid vertex attribute index. Wanted index: 4294967295. Max index: 16
```

I'm tried somehow fix it using `glBufferData` and `glBufferSubData`, but have no success. 
Maybe there is an example or wiki how to do it right?

Comment: `ArrayList` is not a thread safe so you should make it synchronized try Collections.synchronizedList()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ConcurrentModification error, which means you are trying to access the rendering pipeline from a different thread than the OpenGL is rendered on.

This should be the way to do that:

```
glSurfaceView.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mGLRenderer.AddFigure(1f, 1f, 1f);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks!